# Login Error Failed for the regions not in US

Tags: sql, excel, string, connection

I currently took over an excel application project in my job. The issue is that when our colleagues are trying to run a macro from this excel file and generate a report, they get the error message **"Login failed for user 'xxx\username"**

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this and provide access to my colleague to run the report. This situation is not experienced by anyone within the same location, but fewer employees located at different country location experience this error.

```
       dbs.Open "Data Source = 00.00.0.00; Initial Catalog = Toyata; Trusted_connection = Yes; Provider = SQLOLEDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            dbs.CommandTimeout = 0
```

Comment: Are your users logging in under a different domain?  For example, "UK\Username" instead of "US\Username"?  This may not be a programming problem.  It could be Active directory and/or folder permissions issue.

Comment: Yeah. They are logging in from the India location

Comment: I'd treat this as a connection issue, not a programming issue.  Check ODBC settings on the india machine (I think thats an ODBC connection?) for a start.

Comment: They have been accessing the same application few weeks ago, while it was working fine. But in recent week, fewer having complaining of running the excel macro